# Create dynamic Excel files based on a template, using XML data

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I'm currently looking for a way to create dynamic excel files, based on an existing template, using data coming from an XML-file.
For example;
I have a template ExcelTemplate.xlsx with some layouting in it. A user calls a method which will create a copy of the template and fill it with data coming from an XML. After that the user will get a MemoryStream returned with the newly created xlsx.

Anyone has an idea how to work this out in the best possible way? This is supposed to run on a server (as a service) where there isn't any office installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've worked out a solution for this, using [ExcelPackage.](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate a bit on your solution?
I'm mainly interested to see how your excel template looks like.

Answer (score 2):

When writing this yourself (*no other tools used) you could consider using an XSLT transform. Use the template as basis for your XSLT, push in the XML data as parameter(s) into the XSLT transform, get a new XML out (your new xslx)

Hope this helps,

Comment: I'm not fully understanding what you're saying.. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Although possible - I'm not sure I would want to try to hand code and test an XSLT manually without any tools or a working base template to start with.

Comment: My intention of saying "without any tools" is refereing too explicit toolkits like the ones mentioned by Andrew.

I would, of course, advise the use of a good XML/XSLT toolkit to build the XSLT(s) you would need for this solution (one of my personal prefernces being XMLSpy or Visual Studio).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at these projects:

- [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) - Mature and Stable but does not yet support the xlsx (Open XML) format yet.
- [ExtremeML](http://www.extrememl.com/) - Alpha and Active - Looks promising.
- [SimpleOOXML](http://simpleooxml.codeplex.com/) - Stable and Active
- [XOOX](http://xoox.codeplex.com/)  - Alpha and Active - Still young.

I think [ExtremeML](http://www.extrememl.com/) is the best match to your requirements. It has very good support for working with template xslx documents and is extensible.

Comment: Was already working with the SimpleOOXML-lib, but thanks for mentioning again. It's a great lib.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of doing the following:

- Create a template.xlsx and a templatesettings.xml.

The templatesettings.xml will containt the startrow & startcol of the table which I want to fill.

- Create an xlsx from the template, using OpenXml. Some code will iterate trough my data, and because I know where I have to start inputting my data (templatesettings.xml), I should be able to fill all data errorfree..

My solution is based on following tut:
[Creating Spreadsheets from a server application](http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/Creating_Spreadsheets_Server.aspx)

Let's hope this works as good as it works in my head.